# terminating with uncaught exception of type CKException

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

I can't figure out why but my app keeps crashing when ever I try to save a CKRecord in my data base and I get this error message, "terminating with uncaught exception of type CKException." Any input will be much appreciated. Heres my code:

```
func saveCountryMood(countryToSave:String) {

    // Create CK record
    let newRecord:CKRecord = CKRecord(recordType: realCurrentCountry)
    newRecord.setValue(countryToSave, forKey: "Country")

    // Save record into public database
    if let database = self.publicDatabase {

        database.saveRecord(newRecord, completionHandler: { (record:CKRecord!, error:NSError!) -> Void in

            // Check for error
            if error != nil {

                // There was an error
                NSLog(error.localizedDescription)

            }
            else {
                // There was no error
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

                    // Refresh table
                    self.retrieveCountryMoods("")

                }

            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Provide more details about the exception. Which line causes the crash? What's the error message?

Comment: Crashes on this line: let newRecord:CKRecord = CKRecord(recordType: realCurrentCountry)

Comment: Exact error message is as follows:      libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type CKException

Comment: There must be more to the error message.

Comment: Ahh you are right my bad here it is---- Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CKException', reason: 'recordType (United States) contains invalid characters'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: Now you know how to fix the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a space in your recordType. You could replace this by something else.

You do have to be aware that in production you are not allowed to create a new recordType. All recordTypes must already exist (created on development). So all different values of realCurrentCountry have to be created on development.